# When using ggvis with data table I'm receiving "Error: This code should not be reached"

Tags: r, data.table, visualization, ggvis

When I type the following code

```
library(data.table)
library(ggvis)

age <- as.integer(c(1,4,8,5,4,3,2,4,5,4,3))
disk <- c(3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3)
dt <- data.table(age, disk)
df <- data.frame(age, disk)

dt %>%
  ggvis(x=~age) %>%
  layer_histograms()

df %>%
  ggvis(x=~age) %>%
  layer_histograms()
```

When the data frame is used the histogram is produced. However when the data table is used, I get the error message:

```
Guessing width = 2 # range / 30
Error: This code should not be reached.
```

No plot prints. Can someone please tell me why the data table input produces this error?

Thanks

Comment: @Pascal apologies, its reproducible now.

Comment: According to [this page](http://ggvis.rstudio.com/ggvis-basics.html), there is a workaround using `compute_bin()`.

Comment: That does work, however seems computationally expensive and maybe not worthwhile when working with a large data set. I appreciate your response, thanks.

Comment: `ggvis` is deep in development, so I suppose its' interaction with `data.table` is not polished yet. Wrap `dt %>% as.data.frame %>% ...` and you're good.